# Reassign result value of a module to one of it's ports in Verilog

Tags: module, verilog, sequential

I've spend so time implementing an algorithm in Verilog. I have to use float point numbers, so FPU module is used to compute all operations result(+, -, *, /). FPU module instantiation, out is the result of operand (fpu_op) applied on opa, and opb, both 32-bit reg s that represents IEEE754 float numbers:

```
fpu  inst0 (.clk(clk), .rmode(rmode), .fpu_op(fpu_op), .opa(opa), .opb(opb), .out(fout));
```

I wonder if it's okay to reassign value  in always block as in following code:
(rcmp_1 is the result of float comparison made also in a module)

```
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(rcmp_1[0] & !rcmp_1[1]) begin
      opa <= x;
      opb <= ftwo;
      fpu_op <= mul;
      x <= fout;
    end
  end
```

So my question is: Will x contain value of fout at the end of if block, and can i futher use computed value of x in other always blocks?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on declarations.  All lhs vars should be registers.

Answer (score 1):

Your always block models a set of 4 registers (without reset) that are enabled by the condition rcmp_1 equal to '01'.
When the condition is true, at the rising edge of the clock the output of the four registers, that are named opa , opb, fpu_op, and x become equal to:
opa equal to the actual value of x
opb equal to ftwo,
fpu_op equal to mul,
the next value of x becomes equal to fout.
So in my opinion the answer to your first question is YES.

Aslo, you can use x (connect the output of the register with output 'x') in other always blocks (circuits). YES also to the second question.

I would write your code as:

```
    assign enable = (rcmp_1==2'b01);   // enable signal on 1bit
    
    always @ (posedge clk)   // register for fpu_op
    begin
        if(enable)      fpu_op <= mul;
    end
    
    always @ (posedge clk)   // register for x
    begin
        if(enable)   x <= fout;
    end
    
    always @ (posedge clk)   // register for opa
    begin
        if(enable)  opa <= x;
    end
    
    always @ (posedge clk) // register for opb
    begin
        if(enable) opb <= ftwo;
    end
```

Comment: this assuming that declaration of *rcmp_1* is `[1:0]`. Why did you rewrite the model in such a way? What is the reason? also fpu_op, opa, opb and 'x' must be registers.

Comment: >> this assuming that declaration of rcmp_1 is [1:0].
YES
>>  also fpu_op, opa, opb and 'x' must be registers. 
YES
>> Why did you rewrite the model in such a way?
It is easier to understand if you associate the code to the actual circuit (one outpu associated to one block). The declaration of the enabble signal eases the job for the synthesizer that knows that the same signal is needed for all the registers.

Comment: you should probably add declaration requirements to the answer, since OP did not provide them. The rest about the synthesizer is questionable. Your style will not help synthseizer and requires more typing but it could be helpful in some cases. Using it is a matter of a personal prefernce.